# Same source folder in to TFS systems?

Tags: tfs, workspace

I have to maintain the same sources in 2 different TFS systems.
One is in the local network, the other is reachable over a VPN.
(So the other one is not always available.)
When trying to do the second mapping, TFS shows the error: 
"The path X is already mapped in workspace Y" (which is correct).

I also tried to create a separate workspace, but this gives the same error.

I once created a workaround by mapping the same disk to another drive letter
(like "Z" and "Y"). But I'm wondering, if this is really without problems, with respect to the temporary files TFS puts on the disk.

So my question is: Is there an official way to map the same folder to 2 different TFS systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Git, it's not possible to map two different TFS sever folders(also two TFS systems) to the **same local filesystem path**, or to overlapping filesystem paths. It's also regardless of whether the two mappings are in the same workspace, or in two different workspaces.

Workspaces and their mappings are managed and stored on the TFS server, the server is capable of enforcing this restriction across all workspaces on the same machine.

Comment: I found a workaround by mapping the same folder by network share, like \\groove\z$\cust\abc\def. Could this work in all cases, especially regarding the hidden temporary files, created by TFS on the disk?

Comment: @cskwg Afraid not, tfs store the temporary files in a `temp` folder which is not in the workspace.  Besides, there are two different servers at all will not share the temporary files. The easiest solution is using GIT in TFS. If you are using Git version control, you could add more than one remote server for your local git repository. Just follow this tutorial https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/ to do the migrate If you insist on TFVC, a workaround should be using a tool/script to remove the bindings before committing to another TFS. Such as Unbind or ExportSrc

Comment: Hi Patrick, for the time being I opted for using a separate folder and doing a manual merge between the 2 folders. Thank you very much!